# I have El Capitan and can not install a DMG file

Tags: macos, dmg

I get an error message that says:

> Warning. The following disk images couldn't be opened.
>   Image Reason SurveillanceClient.dmg invalid checksum

Does anyone have ideas on how to install this file?

Comment: You need to check that the download has not corrupted the file - a good site should have a checksum allowing you to check this

Answer (score 1):

In [this YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yG5aNcxhbXU), they teach you how to fix this. Anyway, after El Capitan, Disk Utility has been completely changed, so now, in order to disable the checksum verification, you can just open a Terminal window and type:

```
defaults write com.apple.frameworks.diskimages skip-verify -bool true
```

Then open again your .dmg. Now it should work.

Comment: But you should not disable the checksum check - without knowing why it was corrupted first - do you want a Trojan?

Comment: Ok i got the file to mount and the installation to open but at the end of the install it says Instillation Failed , the Installer encountered an error that caused the installation to fail. Contact software manufacturer for assistance. I contacted them and they swear it's apples fault. Any ideas?

Comment: Open Disc Utility > Images > Verify > Select your .dmg file. What's the result of this operation?

Comment: Operation failed with status 116

Answer (score 1):

I was getting this error in High Sierra and it had been bugging me for a while.

So I investigated the volumes I had mounted using Disk Utility and found that there were *two* uninitialized volumes remaining that I couldn't format, mount or erase.

What solved the problem for me, was clicking the Apple symbol in the upper-right hand corner and searching for 'Force Quit'. I relaunched Finder and logged out immediately, not re-opening any applications...

Then I logged back in after I had been logged out and clicked Finder > Applications > Utilities && finally I opened the 'Terminal' application.

**MAKE SURE NO DISK IMAGES ARE MOUNTED OR OPEN**

Once in Terminal, I typed the following:

`sudo chmod 775 /Volumes`

typed in my password, and mounted my disk image!

Voila!